# Incorrect SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) count

Tags: excel, vba

SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) gives incorrect row count as well as range size

Sample data (145rows):
[image]

When filter applied (should be 142 rows, variant contains 16):
[image]

Tried different machines same output. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: That count is of only the first [area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas).  One would need to loop the areas and add the count of each.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285897/row-count-on-the-filtered-data - check the first answer for guidance.

Comment: thanks, but was it always like that? That it only return first consecutive results? found this which solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897753/get-a-filtered-range-into-an-array
but still odd...

Comment: @PetrasK it was like that at least since 2010 :)