# VBA: Set an Array equal to filter criteria

Tags: excel, vba, filter

Currently I have data that is already filtered business type. I want to fill an array with the values from another column without any repeats. In other terms I want to fill an array with the filter criteria from another column.

The filter criteria in the other column will change depending on what business type is selected so filling the array needs to be dynamic.

I've researched this online and so far have only found this which doesn't work:

```
Dim tempArr As Variant

tempArr = Sheets("Sheet1").Filters.Criteria1
```

Sample Data

```
buisUnit   ProfCenter
SHS        1
SHS        1
SHS        2
SHS        3
SHS        4
ALT        5
ALT        6
ALT        6
ALT        7
```

So if my data is filtered on buis unit = SHS I would want tempArray = (1,2,3,4)
if filtered on ALT i would want (5,6,7)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show sample data so that it will be easily visualized.

Comment: `Worksheet`s do not have a `Filters` property. They have `AutoFilter.Filters` but we need to see your code before we can make suggestions. Another thing, the `s` at the end of `Filters` indicates a collection, which means you need to use an index to access a certain filter (`Filters(1)` and so on)

Comment: What "without any repeats" does mean? Do you want saying unique values?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes. Look at my edited post.

Comment: @WilsMils Sample data is now included

Comment: You asked the wrong question. According to your example the question should be: "How to set an array equal to the **filtered data** (without duplicates)". If you research for that you would find answers to your question like: [Get a filtered range into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897753/get-a-filtered-range-into-an-array). The duplicates need then to be removed in a second step [VBA Removing duplicates values in an array including the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877273/vba-removing-duplicates-values-in-an-array-including-the-same-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the next function, please. It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'. If you cannot add it (even if it is extremely simple), just comment the first declaration line and un-comment the second one:

```
Function FilterArray(arr As Variant, strSearch As String) As Variant
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    'Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i As Long, strKey As String
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
      If arr(i, 1) = strSearch Then
        strKey = arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)
        If Not dict.Exists(strKey) Then
           dict.Add strKey, arr(i, 2)
        End If
      End If
  Next i
   If dict.Count = 0 Then FilterArray = "": Exit Function
   FilterArray = dict.Items
End Function
```

It would be called in the next way:

```
Sub testFilterArr()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, strSearch As String, lastRow As Long
  
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastRow).Value
   strSearch = "SHS"
   arr = FilterArray(arr, strSearch)
   If IsArray(arr) Then
       Debug.Print Join(arr, ",")
   Else
       MsgBox "No any result for """ & strSearch & """..."
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Wils Mils: Glad I could help! Important would be that the one asking the question will test it, too... :)